# BrowserSync not working with Windows 10

Tags: node.js, gulp, browser-sync

I've got this gulpfile.js (below)  on my Windows 10 machine. 
On Windows 7 everything was fine. Everything I installed few hours ealier. 
UAC is disabled, When I'm starting without admin right I got this error. 
When using admin rights Browser Sync is starting forever. 
Also I installed Visual Studio

```
[20:12:47] 'browser-sync' errored after 16 ms
[20:12:47] Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'D:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-1035505530-3282241661-3853854261-1002'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:761:18)
    at Glob._readdir (D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\node_modules\globule\node_modules\glob\glob.js:577:20)
    at Glob._process (D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\node_modules\globule\node_modules\glob\glob.js:379:15)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\node_modules\globule\node_modules\glob\glob.js:403:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\node_modules\globule\node_modules\glob\glob.js:402:9)
    at Glob._readdir (D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\node_modules\globule\node_modules\glob\glob.js:554:32)
    at Glob._process (D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\node_modules\globule\node_modules\glob\glob.js:379:15)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\node_modules\globule\node_modules\glob\glob.js:403:14)

events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
    at listen (net.js:1182:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
    at Object.module.exports.startServer [as fn] (D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\async.js:116:39)
    at D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\UI.js:181:14
    at iterate (D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\async-each-series\index.js:8:5)
    at D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\async-each-series\index.js:16:16
    at D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\UI.js:189:13
    at Object.module.exports.setUrlOptions [as fn] (D:\projects\xampp\htdocs\sample\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\async.js:72:9)

// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// Include Our Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
// var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

// Lint Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
return gulp.src('js/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

// Compile Our Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());

});

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src('js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// Browser sync
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
     browserSync.init({
        proxy: "adrian.dev"
 });
 gulp.watch(path+"/*.scss", ['styles']);
 gulp.watch(path+'/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
 gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
 gulp.watch("js/*.js").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
browserSync.init({
    proxy: "adrian.dev"
});
gulp.watch("scss*.scss", ['sass']);
gulp.watch('/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
gulp.watch("js/*.js").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// // Reloading
// gulp.task('js-watch', ['lint'], browserSync.reload);

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['lint', 'scripts']);
gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);

});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'sass', 'scripts', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Comment: for the second error, it looks like it's trying to listen on a port that is already in use.

Comment: I tried to change that for different port but without success. Everytime it starting with the same port